# How do you enable Enterprise Search Center for individual site collections?

Tags: 2013, search, administration, site-template, enterprise-search

Currently I've setup an Enterprise Search Center from central admin for the farm, but what I need is the ability for each site collection owner to create their own Enterprise Search Center site.

So instead of:
http://local/sites/search/

It would be:
http://local/sites/siteA/search/
http://local/sites/siteB/search/
http://local/sites/siteC/search/

Right now site collection owners aren't seeing the Enterprise Search Center site template.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. I needed to add "SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features" to site collection features for each site.

Comment: The enterprise search center has Publishing features turned on. You may want to use a basic search center instead. Usually you will provision only one Enterprise Search Center as a top level site in a site collection, or a sub-site in a publishing site collection.